# replace the values using iflelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have a very trivial question with the data as below :

```
sample<-list(c(10,12,17,7,9,10),c(NA,NA,NA,10,12,13),c(1,1,1,0,0,0))
sample<-as.data.frame(sample)
colnames(sample)<-c("x1","x2","D")

>sample
x1  x2  D
10  NA  1
12  NA  1
17  NA  1
7   10  0
9   20  0
10  13  0
```

Note:  the number of observations with D=1 is same as D=0

Now, I want to create a variable `x3` that has values related to `D=0` when `D=1` and values related to `D=1` when `D=0`. The expected output:

```
x1  x2  D   x3
10  NA  1   10
12  NA  1   20
17  NA  1   13
7   10  0   NA
9   20  0   NA
10  13  0   NA
```

I tried using `ifelse` function as follows:

```
sample.data$x3<-with(sample.data, ifelse(D==1,x2[which(D==0)],x2[which(D==1)]))
```

I got the following error:

```
logical(0)
```

I also tried the following:

```
sample.data$x3<-with(sample.data, ifelse(D==1,tail(x2,3),head(x2,3)))
```

Again, I got the same error:

```
logical(0)
```

Any idea what is going here?

Comment: `sample$x3 <- sample$x2[order(sample$D)]`

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic in your command is sound, but you are referencing the dataframe incorrectly.  You just need to remove `.data` after `sample` throughout your line of code.  So this command will give you what you need:

```
sample$x3<-with(sample,ifelse(D==1,x2[which(D==0)],x2[which(D==1)]))
```

---

That code is still a little verbose however.

As @Arun has noted in the comments, you don't need to include the which() function when selecting `x2` values to use as a result of your `ifelse`.  The following code will give you identical results:

```
sample$x3<-with(sample,ifelse(D==1,x2[D==0],x2[D==1]))
```

Comment: Sure.  I'd also note that you're creating that dataframe in a bit of a strange way--I would do it in one line like so: `sample<-data.frame(x1=c(10,12,17,7,9,10), x2=c(NA,NA,NA,10,20,13), D=c(1,1,1,0,0,0))`.  You might want to [brush up on data frames a bit](http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/R/dataframe.php).

Comment: (+1) you don't need a `which` there, do you?

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the note @Arun, I've added a note on removing the which() function for succinctness.

Answer (score 5):

do you know `data.table`, here is a solution with it...

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

sample = as.data.table(sample)
sample[,x4:=ifelse(D==1,x2[D==0],x2[D==1])]
```

Comment: @ statquant: Yeah, I know the data.table but haven't used a lot. Thanks for the solution.